# Why do I get a winError 193 when I am importing Matplotlib using Spyder on a Windows 10 (64-bit ) machine?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, anaconda

I am using a Windows 10(64-bit) machine and have installed Anaconda. I tried to execute this line of code in Spyder:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

however, I get this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7b260cc15e44> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    139 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    140 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 141 from . import cbook, rcsetup
    142 from matplotlib.cbook import (
    143     MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, dedent, get_label, sanitize_sequence)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in <module>
     31 from weakref import WeakMethod
     32 
---> 33 import numpy as np
     34 
     35 import matplotlib

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     21             # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     22             # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 23             WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     24             DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     25     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I tried importing matplotlib in Jupyter notebook and directly in Anaconda Shell as well. However, I get the same error everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We all create an account for a question. Yours is hard !
1. Are your sure your are using the python3 from anaconda `import sys ; print sys.executable`. 2. Reduce your problem with just `import numpy`. And well 3/ reinstall numpy : `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`.